# Error (403) Forbidden after successfull authentication on Google Calendar API with Xamarin.Auth

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing a Xamarin app (iOS, Android, OSX and Windows) and have to implement calendar synchronization between the app and one user calendar.

This is what I have tried:

```
Account userAccount;
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
               "xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", //cliendID
               "xxxxxxx", //clientSecret
               CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, //scope
               new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"), //authorizationURI
               new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"), //redirectURI
               new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")); //tokeUri

auth.Completed += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(e.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        userAccount = e.Account;

        var request = new OAuth2Request(
                    "GET",
                    new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList"),
                    null,
                    userAccount);

        request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            if(r.IsFaulted)
            {
                var a = r.Exception.InnerException.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                var json = r.Result.GetResponseText();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
                //Show message that something failed
    }
};
```

The problem is that `e.IsAuthenticated` returns true but once I try to get the calendar list to which I pass the userAccount I got in the step before I get the 403 error (`e.IsFaulted` is true).

Any ideas what I need to do to get the list of calendars?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the Google .net client library?

Comment: Because there isn't a mono implementation (at least I couldn't find any). There is a .NET version but then I get an error for not having a reference for `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`. As I said this is a Xamarin app

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/   If its not working pop an issue up here as far as i know it should be supported https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: I did and as I have found on my own they also can't get it to run. They hoped it worked out of the box once they targeted .net standard but as it turned out there needs to be a little more done for that.

Comment: Thanks for posting it on the forum.   I will try to find some more time to play with it.